What does "反故" actual mean

何度も希望を待って臨み
何度も反故とされてきたあの海の遠さを
そして深さを

This is a monologue. As far I can see it uses a somewhat poetic style. The character, trapped on an island, reflect another character gazing at the sea they can't cross.
"反故" means "scrap paper" so why is it used here? Does it have some kind of nuance not on dictionaries?

反故にする is an idiom that means to unilaterally break a contract or promise. It should be listed in any dictionary. 反故とする is less common, but carries the same meaning. It's typically used like this:

契約を反故にされて大きな損失を被った。
The contract was unilaterally nullified, causing us to suffer a significant loss.

Your example is not the most typical usage of 反故とする since the sea hasn't made any promise to the speaker. Still, the speaker's feeling of being "betrayed by the sea" is conveyed through this phrase.

I see. To be honest, i was wondering if it was  "とされて" for "considered" (considered useless?)
